# How can I determine which encoding JSON.stringify() used?

Tags: json, node.js, encoding, content-type, v8

I'm putting together a node/express app which will be returning JSON that was serialized using `JSON.stringify()`.  I'd like to set the `Content-Type` HTTP header to include encoding info--such as `application/json; charset=utf-16`.

My understanding is that `JSON.stringify()` might produce `UTF-16` or `UCS-2` encoded results.  How do I know which encoding was used to serialize JSON, and what's the best way to inform user-agents of the correct encoding?

Comment: I was mistaken about `UCS-2` and `UTF-16`.  They're used internally for javascript runtimes, but not necessarily related to `JSON.stringify()`.  However, I'm still curious how to check what encoding was used (or for a reference that shows that `JSON.stringify()` can/will only produce `UTF-8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, it returns an instance of the type `String`, that is defined as a sequence of zero or more 16-bit unsigned integers (see the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)).

I cite the link above:

> A String value is a member of the String type. Each integer value in the sequence usually represents a single 16-bit unit of UTF-16 text. However, ECMAScript does not place any restrictions or requirements on the values except that they must be 16-bit unsigned integers.

Because of that, I guess it's implementation defined. [This](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4) is maybe the part of the spec that is of interest for you.